# How can this strange behaviour of console.log() in vue.js be explained?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, console.log, google-developer-tools

When I use the first code sample, for some reason `console.log()` gives me the processed HighData variable. As if the `console.log()` were at the end of the script.

```js
console.log( "data", this.data['diagram'] );
var HighData = this.data['diagram'];

minSerieHeight = getMin( HighData[3] );
HighData[0] = mkSerie( HighData[0] );
HighData[1] = mkSerie( HighData[1] );
HighData[2] = mkSerie( HighData[2] );
HighData[3] = mkSerie( HighData[3] );
```

Whats even more strange is, when I use `array.map()` (which does exactly the same thing as the code above) it returns the `this.data['diagram']` variable correctly as expected.

```js
console.log( "data", this.data['diagram'] );
var HighData = this.data['diagram'];

minSerieHeight = getMin( HighData[ HighData.length - 1 ] );
HighData = HighData.map( e => {
    return mkSerie( e );
});
```

The code is in a Vue component in the `mounted()` function. The `getMin()` and `mkSerie()` are also in the `mounted()` function.

Comment: can you add the 2 logs you get ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding this right - if this code is in the `mounted()` function, why is it wrapped in `<script>` tags?

Comment: @Lewis for stackoverflow. It don't get the language right without it.

Comment: @Silvan You don't need to include `<script>` tags for that. Put triple backticks before and after your code and put the desired language after the opening backticks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Console logging an object/array is 'live'. The console just stores a reference to the object. The values of the properties aren't captured until you expand the object in the console, by which time your object will have changed.

`JSON.stringify` can be useful to capture a string version of the object. As it's a string it can be logged without any risk of it changing. For that to work it does require that the object can be converted to JSON, which is not always possible.

The `map` example is a bit different. You aren't mutating the same object that was logged. Just assigning a new value to `HighData` won't change the value seen in the console as that is still pointing at the original object.

Comment: It works with `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( this.data['diagram'] ) )`.

Comment: omg, how did I not know this? Really explains why I get confused sometimes thank you!